# Firemonkey does strange, bizarre things with Alpha

Tags: delphi, shader, firemonkey, hlsl, alphablending

Working with Delphi / Firemonkey XE8. Had some decent luck with it recently, although you have to hack the heck out of it to get it to do what you want. My current project is to evaluate it's Low-Level 3D capabilities to see if I can use them as a starting point for a Game Project. I also know Unity3D quite well, and am considering using Unity3D instead, but I figure that Delphi / Firemonkey might give me some added flexibility in my game design because it is so minimal.

So I decided to dig into an Embarcadero-supplied sample... specifically the LowLevel3D sample. This is the cross-platform sample that shows you how to do nothing other than draw a rotating square on the screen with some custom shaders of your choice and have it look the same on all platforms (although it actually doesn't work AT ALL the same on all platforms... but we won't get into that).

Embc does not supply the original uncompiled shaders for the project (which I might add is really lame), and requires you to supply your own compatible shaders (some compiled, some not) for the various platforms you're targeting (also lame)...so my first job has been to create a shader that would work with their existing sample that does something OTHER than what the sample already does. Specifically, if I'm creating a 2D game, I wanted to make sure that I could do sprites with alpha transparency, basic stuff.... if I can get this working, I'll probably never have to write another shader for the whole game.

After pulling my hair out for many hours, I came up with this little shader that works with the same parameters as the demo.

```
Texture2D mytex0: register(t0);
Texture2D mytex1: register(t1);
float4 cccc : register(v0) ;   

struct PixelShaderInput
{
    float4 Pos: COLOR;
    float2 Tex: TEXCOORDS;

};

SamplerState g_samLinear
{
 Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
 AddressU = Wrap;
 AddressV = Wrap;
};

RasterizerState MyCull {
  FrontCounterClockwise = FALSE;
};

float4 main(PixelShaderInput pIn): SV_TARGET
{
  float4 cc,c;
  float4 ci = mytex1.Sample(g_samLinear, pIn.Tex.xy);
  c = ci;
  c.a = 0;//<----- DOES NOT actually SET ALPHA TO ZERO ... THIS IS A PROBLEM
  cc = c;
  return cc;
}
```

Never-mind that it doesn't actually do much with the parameters, but check out the line where I set the output's ALPHA to 0.  Well.... I found that this actually HAS NO EFFECT!

But it gets spookier than this. I found that turning on CULLING in the Delphi App FIXED this issue. So I figure... no big deal then, I'll just manually draw both sides of the sprite... right? Nope! When I manually drew a double sided sprite.. **the problem came back**!

Check this image: [shader is ignoring alpha=0 when double-sided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jp5T.png)

In the above picture, clearly alpha is SOMEWHAT obeyed because the clouds are not surrounded by a black box, however, the cloud itself is super saturated (I find that if I multiply rgb*a, then the colors come out approximately right, but I'm not going to do that in real-life for obvious reasons.

I'm new to the concept of writing custom shaders. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Take advice from a game developer and stay clear of trying to use FireMonkey for any serious game.  Even if only doing 2D graphics you can quickly bring FireMonkey to a single digit FPS. Unfotunately FireMonkey seriously lack in performance needed for any serious game project. Sure in the end it allows you to do low level calls but that is almost like writing a whole graphical engine from start. So instead I would recommend you to try `Pascal extended Library` (http://www.afterwarp.net/products/pxl) which is as successor of a well know Asphyre Sphinx graphical library. ...

Comment: ... If you need any additional help feel free to join us on http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/ which is a dedicated forum for developing games using Object Pascal.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll have to check out the Pascal Game Development group. I didn't even know it existed.  I already have a 2D Engine that makes DirectX calls, so I thought that I could maybe just make it cross platform by adapting the draw calls to the FMX layer.  The game is a retro-style game, so its power needs are limited, but I don't want to be power-limited. Maybe I'll find some good resources there.

Comment: My other problem with the FMX demo (which I wasn't going to get into) is that after a few minutes, the rotating square on the screen turns solid WHITE.  This is annoying as hell and makes me think I can't trust FMX at all.

Comment: Adapting the draw calls to FMX would be just adding a new abstract layer between your 2D engine and the hardware. It would be better if you instead adapt your graphical engine to make proper calls to OpenGL. This way you get ability to port it to multiple platforms as OpenGL and its variants like OpenGL ES are basically what is used on other platforms. Now if you decide to try out the Pascal Extended Library as I suggested you will see that it already has support for DirectX (versions from 7 to 11) and various OpenGL versions. ...

Comment: ... Also its author added software rendering support which allows it to be used on some other non conventional platforms like Raspberry PI ir Single board computers. Now for this you do need to compile your program with FPC/Lazarus instead of Delphi since Delphi does not support those platforms.

Comment: BTW you say you already have an existing 2D engine. Which engine is this if I may ask?

Comment: My 2D engine is just something I whipped up a while back.  I whip up lots of things.  I thought about using FMX because the Low-Level stuff already adapts OpenGL to DirectX.  I'm burnt out for today, but I'll get back to it.  Maybe Unity3D is the best answer... I dunno.

Comment: @SilverWarior thanks for the PXL recommendation.  This framework looks like a pretty awesome starting point, exactly what I need, and looks nice, clean, and reliable so far.  And the cross platform/firemonkey demo actually WORKED for more than 5 minutes unlike Embarcadero's example.  I think the CORRECT answer to my original question, as cynical as it sounds is "don't use FMX, use PXL instead."   It'll get me where I need to go.  BTW, do you know of anyone who has done joystick input with PXL specifically with the nVidia Sheild/Ouya? I wasn't seeing input samples, but I don't need them ASAP?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know if anybody used that specific controller with PXL or Asphyre Sphinx libraries. Your best bet would be to open ask PXL developer or perhaps even better post a question on Pascal Game Development because there are few developers that were actually developing some of their games to be compatible with Ouya platform. They were using FPC/Lazarus for this because at the time Delphi still had no Android support so if they decide to share their code it might have to be changed a bit in order to work with Delphi.